# Why doesn't my email regex for PHP work?

Tags: php, regex

I have the same expression in Javascript but it won't work in PHP for server side validation.  Here's the code

```
if (ereg('/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+/',$_POST['email-address']))
    echo "valid email";
else
    echo "invalid email";
```

Comment: Your regex appears to be in preg_match format rather than ereg format... most notably the leading and trailing / characters.

Comment: Does your regex handle "+" in the name part? On first glance it looks like it doesn't.  Theres a good article on handling emails as regex here http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Great, another e-mail "validator" in regexes... :-( Gumbo's advice is good!
BTW, the ([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+ looks strange. And I wonder why you are doing so much captures and not using them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate an emailaddress in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-emailaddress-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use preg_match, not ereg. ereg regex strings do not use an enclosing slash character.

Also the double-backslash may not be necessary in a single-quoted string in PHP (not sure about that, though)

Answer (score 9):

filter which comes with PHP:

```
if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

echo "E-mail is not valid";

} else {

echo "E-mail is valid";

}
```

Comment: I can provide you a list of valid email addresses that FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL says are invalid.

Answer (score 7):

[Don't use regular expressions to "validate" email addresses](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-September/404146.html)

*Edit:* Link is broken. [This is probably the right link](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2006-September/455468.html)

Comment: Wish I could upvote more than once. This really is a TFAQ (too frequently asked question)...

Answer (score 3):

I use the following. I also would run TRIM() on the input string before comparing it:

```
function is_email($string) {
  if (preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/',$string)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've now collated test cases from Cal Henderson, Dave Child, Phil Haack, Doug Lovell and RFC 3696. 158 test addresses in all.

I ran all these tests against all the validators I could find. The comparison is here: http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail

I'll try to keep this page up-to-date as people enhance their validators. Thanks to Cal, Dave and Phil for their help and co-operation in compiling these tests and constructive criticism of [my own validator](http://code.google.com/p/isemail/source/browse/trunk/is_email.php).

People should be aware of the [errata against RFC 3696](http://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=3696) in particular. Three of the canonical examples are in fact invalid addresses. And the maximum length of an address is 254 or 256 characters, **not** 320.

Answer (score -1):

It could be because of the symbol you are using to concatenate the expressions (+).

Anyways you should try this one:

\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*

Comment: That's not concatenation, it means a character set must be included "once or more times".