# How consistent is FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL?

Tags: php, email, filtering

Sample valid e-mail address:

> "this is a valid address"@example.com

PHP code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

$email = '"this is a valid address"@example.com';
$checked = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
var_dump($email, $checked);
```

Output on one server: (PHP Version 5.2.6):

> string(37) ""this is a valid address"@example.com"
>   string(37) ""this is a valid address"@example.com"

`phpinfo()`:

```
Input Validation and Filtering      enabled
Revision                            $Revision: 1.52.2.42 $

Directive             Local Value   Master Value
filter.default        unsafe_raw    unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags  no value      no value
```

Output on another server (PHP Version 5.3.3):

> string(37) ""this is a valid address"@example.com"
>   bool(false)

`phpinfo()`:

```
Input Validation and Filtering      enabled
Revision                            $Revision: 298196 $

Directive             Local Value   Master Value
filter.default        unsafe_raw    unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags  no value      no value
```

I cannot see anything in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) to suggest that this has changed, so perhaps it's some other configuration setting.

Comment: [Tests for PHP mail validation](http://fightingforalostcause.net/misc/2006/compare-email-regex.php), [Semi related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863), [Commits](https://github.com/php/php-src/commits/master/ext/filter/logical_filters.c) and [Changelog](http://nl.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php). Conclusion: no not consistent ;-) it has been improved a couple of times.

Comment: **That might be a valid email address but anyone using it is not really valid... in the `<head>`.** *If you CAN do some things, it does not really mean you SHOULD.* I'd absolutely NEVER send an email to an address like that, out of respect for sanity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see on http://3v4l.org/vKONS the usage of the filter `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` it is not consistent!

http://3v4l.org/vKONS outputs for PHP 5.2.0, 5.2.14 - 5.2.17, 5.3.3 - 5.3.18, 5.4.0 - 5.4.8

```
string(37) ""this is a valid address"@example.com" 
bool(false)
```

and for 5.2.1 - 5.2.13, 5.3.0 - 5.3.2

```
string(37) ""this is a valid address"@example.com" 
string(37) ""this is a valid address"@example.com"
```

**It is remarkable that it worked for 5.2.0 but not 5.2.1-5.2.13 and then again for 5.2.14!!!**

*Btw [3v4l.org](http://3v4l.org/) is a great resource to check such behavior changes across all available PHP versions.*

There are [several bugs open](https://bugs.php.net/search.php?cmd=display&search_for=FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL&x=9&y=5) including the term FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, but none seems to match your kind of error. You might add it to the [PHP bugtracker](https://bugs.php.net/report.php)...

Comment: Accepted for answering the question. +1 for link to 3v4l.org.