# difference between a javascript and regular expression and filter_var for email validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email, filter-var

i have been thnking about some validation of email using javascript in one hand and filter_var
with neccessary parameters and regular expression using preg_match .now as input sanitaisation has gone in a long run with so many things to keep in mind, wht to use when validating email.

for preg_match `if(!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))`

by javascript

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
{
alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
return false;
}
}
```

by filter_var

```
<?php
if(!filter_var("someone@example....com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo("E-mail is not valid");
}
else
{
echo("E-mail is valid");
}
?>
```

Comment: The difference is: In practice - none, in implementation - a lot. Both will validate your input but I recommend to use the same regex in both cases.

Comment: not in implementation? any other way to handle with more enhancement.
thnx in adv.

Comment: I agree with Eric, you should just use the regex in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those three variants are very different.

- ```
  preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email)
  ```

  This regex is very restrictive - actually, it's too restrictive. It does only allow word characters and minuses around the @-sign and dot. For example, it does not even allow subdomains (which are quite common).
- ```
  var atpos = email.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
  return !(atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  ```

  This looks quite well. It checks for the existence of an `@` and a `.` in the correct order, which is enough to identify email-like looking strings. It could be replaced by the regular expression `/.+@.+\..+/.test(email)` (which would not allow linebreaks, but that's fine).
- ```
  filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
  ```

  [This](http://www.php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.validate.php) is probably the best way to do it in PHP, but notice that is has [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494114/how-consistent-is-filter-validate-email) [flaws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3722831/does-phps-filter-var-filter-validate-email-actually-work) as well.

I would also recommend the article [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/) :-)