# How do I run this regex in PHP that parse full email address with name?

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
^((?>[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+\x20*|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*"\x20*)*(?<angle><))?((?!\.)(?>\.?[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+)+|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*")@(((?!-)[a-zA-Z\d\-]+(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\[(((?(?<!\[)\.)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)){4}|[a-zA-Z\d\-]*[a-zA-Z\d]:((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^\\\[\]]|\\[\x01-\x7f])+)\])(?(angle)>)$
```

Which is suppose to parse full email with name and everything, I couldn't get it to run in PHP, please help?

Here is what I have tried:

```
$test = "Joe Doe <doe@example.com>";
$emailRegex = '@^((?>[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&\'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+\x20*|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*"\x20*)*(?<angle><))?((?!\.)(?>\.?[a-zA-Z\d!#$%&\'*+\-/=?^_`{|}~]+)+|"((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^"\\]|\\[\x01-\x7f])*")@(((?!-)[a-zA-Z\d\-]+(?<!-)\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}|\[(((?(?<!\[)\.)(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d?\d)){4}|[a-zA-Z\d\-]*[a-zA-Z\d]:((?=[\x01-\x7f])[^\\\[\]]|\\[\x01-\x7f])+)\])(?(angle)>)$@';
preg_match($emailRegex, $test, $curResult);
print_r($curResult);
```

Comment: Since you use `@` as your delimiters, you will need to escape your `@` used for the email address (`\@`).

Comment: Please don't create new questions for the same problem.

Comment: It's not the same question, the regex is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple. Since we know we can use this to [validate almost any email address in an uncomplicated way](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/):

```
(^[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[^ ].+$)
```

One step further will let us grab the name too:

```
^(.*?) *(<[^ ]+@[^ ]+\.[^ ].+>)$
```

http://regex101.com/r/wT6uX8

Answer (score 3):

In PHP you don't need a monster regex like that, you can just use the built-in validator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

For example, only the first `echo` will be executed:

```
<?php
$email_a = 'joe@example.com';
$email_b = 'bogus';

if (filter_var($email_a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email_a) email address is considered valid.";
}
if (filter_var($email_b, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This ($email_b) email address is considered valid.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Beware FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13494114/how-consistent-is-filter-validate-email.

Comment: I am not trying to filter email though, I am trying to parse them.

Comment: `var_dump(filter_var("Joe Doe <doe@example.com>", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL));` => false. The OP isn't trying to parse an e-mailaddress, the OP is trying to parse an address string, which is not quite the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would not write a custom function if [PHP's `imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-parse-adrlist.php) does *exactly* what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

> $emailRegex = "/([\w\s]+)\<(\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*)/i";

I hope this will help you