# Regex checking email address allows digits in the top-level domain?

Tags: regex, validation, email

I came across a reg ex for email validation:

```
^[^@]+([@]{1})[0-9a-zA-Z\\._-]+([\\.]{1})[a-zA-Z0-9\\._-]+$
```

This is a pattern which i found in a standard Adobe Day CQ email validation code. I have a problem with the last matching group `[a-zA-Z0-9\\._-]+` where it allows multiple occurrences of digits as well which allows me to enter as a valid input `someone@else.9`. Can somebody please help me understand why do we need a digit value in the last matching group.

Any help is appreciated. Please guide me what else regex can be used to validate a standard
day to day email input.

Comment: Already answered this question once today: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171549/how-do-i-run-this-regex-in-php-that-parse-full-email-address-with-name/21171732#21171732 Same answer stands. Check for spaces, then just send it.

Comment: The regex is horribly broken, as it will allow stuff like `me@...`. Also the `{1}` is a typical newbie mistake - it's harmless but also completely useless. Anyway, don't use regex for email validation.

Comment: Check remus' answer above, it is excellent.