# Matching email regex

Tags: python, regex

SO I'm trying to match an email of this form

```
a-b-c-@-d-e-.-e-f-g
```

I've come up with this regex

```
(\w+(?=-))*-@-(\w+(?=-))*.(\w+(?=-))
```

Why is that not working?

Comment: Not working for which input?

Comment: I'm not sure what this `(?=-)` syntax you're using is supposed to do. I would guess you simply want `-?`.

Comment: You may want something like this: `[\w-]*-@-[\w-]*.[\w-]*`

Comment: @RobinWinslow: That's a look-ahead assertion. It means that `\w+` should only match if followed by a `-`, but won't match the dash itself.

Comment: What is it you're trying to achieve? Remove the hyphens?

Comment: I see now. So the initial `(\w+(?=-))*` will only match `c` because you haven't allowed space for the hyphen before `c` anywhere. I now think what you're looking for is even simpler than my initial suggestion: `(\w+-)*@(-\w+)*.\w+`

Comment: Seriously!? Guys, this question has been asked 3 times today alone. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171549/how-do-i-run-this-regex-in-php-that-parse-full-email-address-with-name/21171732#21171732

Comment: @remus I think you're jumping to conclusions. This is a more specific request than just a simple email address.

Comment: @RobinWinslow I realize that, but I'm aiming to educate here - why spend the time coming up with complicated expressions when we can do away with that entirely?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python check for valid email address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022530/python-check-for-valid-email-address)

Answer (score 3):

You are over-complicating things with the look-ahead assertion. Any look-around assertion acts like an anchor (matches a location in the text, not the text itself); just like `^` and `$` match the start and end of the matched text.

So, `(\w+(?=-)` matches *just* the `a` in the `a-` text. Right after the matched text is the next character, the `-`! So the pattern `(\w+(?=-)*` won't match `a-b-` because there's those dashes in there that are not part of the `\w` character class.

Use a combined character class instead that allows for both `\w` *and* `-` characters, `[\w-]` combines everything `\w` matches with an extra character, `-`:

```
[\w-]*-@-[\w-]*\.[\w-]*
```

You can test this yourself with [this regex101](http://regex101.com/r/vR8fU6) (which includes a full explanation of how it works).

would match your input. I've assumed you wanted to match the *literal* `.` character here, so I used `\.` instead of just `.`, which matches just about anything.

You you need to explicitly match only *single* word characters followed by a dash, repeated, then use:

```
(?:\w-)*@-(?:\w-)*\.(?:-\w)*
```

This pattern is different from your attempt, in that it removes the literal `-` before the `@`, and moves the `-` before the `\w` in the last group. See the [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sU9pK3) for details on the pattern.

Comment: so does this work in python?

Comment: Yes, the regex101 links I provided you are both set to python mode. Why, are they not working for you?

Comment: well those aren't capturing and I'm not sure why that's the case

Comment: @praks5432: for what input? They both match your provided sample input.

Comment: @praks5432: And what method are you using to match your input? `re.search()` or `re.match()`?

Comment: @praks5432: works fine with `findall` too: `re.findall(r'(?:\w-)*@-(?:\w-)*\.(?:-\w)*', 'input text with a-b-c-@-d-e-.-e-f-g in it')`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're aiming to match email addresses in general give this a shot: https://github.com/madisonmay/CommonRegex

Usage is described like this:

```
>>> from commonregex import CommonRegex
>>> parsed_text = CommonRegex("There's an some@email.com in this sentence.")
>>> parsed_text.emails
["some@mail.com"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
(\w|[-])*-@-(\w|[-])*.(\w|[-])*
```

Problem with your code is :

`(?=-)`  is Positive Lookahead which  Assert that the character `-` literally can be matched.
And it will forget the current match still .

Refer **[THIS](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)** .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what your asking for adheres to these rules:

- There's must be only one `.` and one `@`
- There must be a `-` directory either side of the `@` and of the `.`
- The whole string must start and end with a letter
- `-`s must only separate words, never be next to each other

Then I think this will do the trick:

`^(\w+-)*\w+-@-(\w+-)*.(-\w+)*$`

http://regexr.com?381h6