# What email providers allow + in email address?

Tags: php, regex, email, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to validate an email address in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php)

I'm working on my email address validator.

So I've been searching a while and noticed that some emails allows "+" in the email like: hello+guys@email.com

Hotmail doesn't allow a + and neither do yahoo.
**Do you  guys know which ones doesn't allow it?** And I also wonder,  **maybe  there are some old hotmail/yahoo/etc accounts that actually contains the + character?**

What do you think? I dont want my script to deny emails with a + if they  do exists...

Comment: [How to and how **not to** validate an email address in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses

Comment: [Using regular expressions to match email addresses](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: @m.buettner stop that please. Those regex "solutions" will fail

Comment: @PeeHaa if you had read the link I posted, you would know that the conclusion is exactly the same. And that was my point.

Comment: Kilise, kindly do not remove the "Possible Duplicate:" link when closed by the community as a duplicate

Comment: Some do, some don't.  You can't get any more exact than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of valid email characters under the syntax on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address and without going to each mail client and testing each character and email there is no way to tell who allows what.

Answer (score 0):

Reason yahoo, hotmail would not allow it as it is also used as a user name and can lead to unexpected bugs. I do not think that many people out there are using + in there email, it is not the reason to limit your user base.