# With security in mind, what to look for in PHP form validation?

Tags: php, security, email, sendmail, contact-form

I came across a ready-made [contact form on TutWow](http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/create-a-simple-and-secure-contact-form-with-jquery-and-php/) from 2012. It uses [Douglas Lovell's PHP e-mail validation](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/9585?page=0,3) from 2007 that checks whether the email field is valid (even queries DNS servers to see if the domain is valid). Being 6 years old, the question arises — is it still relevant?

In general, what should one usually look for in a `mail()` script for it to be secure but have a minimal footprint? And does Mr. Lovell's script, combined with TutWow's PHP tie-ins, qualify?

Here is the PHP of the combination:

```
<?php

// Clean up the input values
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

  $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
}

// Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

// Test input values for errors
$errors = array();
if(strlen($name) < 2) {
  if(!$name) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Name must be at least 2 characters.";
  }
}
if(!$email) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
} else if(!validEmail($email)) {
  $errors[] = "You must enter a valid email.";
}
if(strlen($message) < 10) {
  if(!$message) {
    $errors[] = "You must enter a message.";
  } else {
    $errors[] = "Message must be at least 10 characters.";
  }
}

if($errors) {
  // Output errors and die with a failure message
  $errortext = "";
  foreach($errors as $error) {
    $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
  }
  die("<span class='failure'>The following errors occured:<ul>". $errortext ."</ul></span>");
}

// Send the email
$to = "YOUR_EMAIL";
$subject = "Contact Form: $name";
$message = "$message";
$headers = "From: $email";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

// Die with a success message
die("<span class='success'>Success! Your message has been sent.</span>");

// A function that checks to see if
// an email is valid
function validEmail($email)
{
   $isValid = true;
   $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
   if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
   {
      $isValid = false;
   }
   else
   {
      $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
      $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
      $localLen = strlen($local);
      $domainLen = strlen($domain);
      if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
      {
         // local part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
      {
         // domain part length exceeded
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
      {
         // local part starts or ends with '.'
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
      {
         // local part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
      {
         // character not valid in domain part
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
      {
         // domain part has two consecutive dots
         $isValid = false;
      }
      else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
      {
         // character not valid in local part unless
         // local part is quoted
         if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
             str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
         {
            $isValid = false;
         }
      }
      if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
      {
         // domain not found in DNS
         $isValid = false;
      }
   }
   return $isValid;
}

?>
```

Comment: From my experience you can lose valid addresses by querying dns. be afraid.

Comment: Won't speak to the security aspect, but potentially making five regex calls AND checking the dns??? That's going to be slow as molasses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This validation is not the best I have seen. What I notice by quickly looking at it is:

- It uses `htmlspecialchars()` without the encoding argument
- It uses `strip_tags()` for a reason I fail to see
- It uses `strlen` instead of `mb_strlen`
- It is vulnerable to header injection
- And the [mail validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863) is not the best I have seen
- There is no CSRF token
- Theer is no captcha

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the safest way would be to send the *sender* an email asking them to confirm that they did indeed send the message. Also, to prevent your contact form being turned into a spam system, limit the number of contact forms each IP address can submit to a reasonable number, probably 1 every 24 hours, assuming replies will be done through regular email.

Comment: Great ideas. Yup, replies done via regular email. Do you know of a ready-made script that features all of this?

Answer (score 0):

Through all my projects, I have found [this guide](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/) to be the most helpful security-wise.

It has many sections including Form processing, Databases and SQL, Sessions, and more.