# Alternative to eregi() in php

Tags: php, eregi

So, i was using eregi in my mail script, but as of lately, i get the error that the function is deprecated.

So, what is the easiest way to replace the following bit of code:

```
if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email'])))?
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: [How to validate an email address in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
 if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9.%-]+@[A-Z0-9.%-]+.[A-Z]{2,4}$/", trim($_POST['email'])))
```

Using preg_match.

Because ereg_* functions is deprecated in PHP >= 5.3

Also for email validation better used [filter_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
if (!filter_var(trim($_POST['email']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    echo 'Email is incorrect';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i tried it now, but it's not sending mails now.
I'm not receiving test mails, and with eregi it works. o.O?

Should i change anything else in my mail script? (if you want, you take a look at the script here http://pastebin.com/q7Mfym9q)

Comment: @Nicholas for email validation better use filter_var() see my answer. I'm updated its

Comment: Hm, thanks for the follow up. I will consider it. In the meantime, i found a solution. When i replace the given line with this
    if (!preg_match("/^[_\.0-9a-zA-Z-]+@([0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {
it works :)

Comment: @Nicholas
Even you can reduce your expression like this
`if(!preg_match("/^[_.\da-z-]+@[a-z\d][a-z\d-]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}$/i", trim($_POST['email'])))`