# Retrieving e-mails from any string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string and I want to retrieve all e-mails contained in that string.

I can get the @domain.com part with this code:

```
 preg_match_all('{@(([^ ]*)\.com)}', $string, $matches);
 print_r($matches[1]);
```

What I want to get is:

```
name@domain.com
```

I used this to make the PHP work:
[getting emails out of string - regex syntax + preg_match_all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050915/getting-emails-out-of-string-regex-syntax-preg-match-all)

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting emails out of string - regex syntax + preg_match_all](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15050915/1438393)

Comment: Note that domains do not all end with ".com".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use a complete email regex :

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

You can find this regex here : http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But my array is empty with that regex code :z

Comment: Adding `^$` to the expression will make it fail since it means that the string should only contain an email address. I'm wondering why this is upvoted that much ...