# Regular expression does not work properly - php

Tags: php, regex

```
elseif(!eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $user_email))
```

Even i tried with `preg_match` in this too i am getting

Warning:

```
preg_match() [function.preg-match]: No ending delimiter '^' found in C:\wamp\www\Saravanan\jQuery\jQuery - Samples\sign_and_login_using_jquery_ajax_and_php\sign_and_login_using_jquery_ajax_and_php\vpb_save_details.php on line 29
Call Stack
```

Comment: I believe the error message is pretty clear. As is [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: Error messages try hard not to lie. And you're using an [obsolete function](http://php.net/eregi)

Comment: Regular expression delimiters: `/regex/`

Comment: And even if you didn't get that error, that still wouldn't be the way to [validate an emailaddress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863)

Comment: POSIX regex are deprecated in PHP 5.. so don't use ereg,eregi etc.. also if ur using preg_match.. enclosed it in delimmeter "/regex/" as in comment by @elclanrs ..

Comment: delimiter will work ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
if(!filter_var($user_email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Comment: +1 I wonder why people don't use this more often.

Comment: Thanks Rashad Aghayev, now its working grate! Chears!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

and if the var comes from POST:

```
if (!filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that there's a slight difference between failing the filter and the variable not being posted though.