# HTML form POST to direct print page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, printing

I have the page VIEW-SALE.PHP
on this page I have a submit button form to view the invoice in print format, there is the code:

```
     <span style='display:inline-block'>
    <form name='print' id='print' action='print-invoice.php' 
target='_blank' method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='invoice' value='$invoice'>
        <input class='submit-all' type='submit' 
value='Print the invoice' 
onClick='window.print();return false'></form></span>
```

The code must just open the page PRINT-INVOICE.PHP and print it but when I click it it show the print dialog but of the current page I am VIEW-SALE.PHP so it does not show the PRINT-INVOICE.PHP

How does it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

doesn't post just post data you may need a header redirect the redirect being php code

```
header("Location: blabla")
```

I found this you may find it of help
[redirect after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157685/php-redirect-to-another-page-after-form-submit)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the `onClick='window.print();return false'`. The `window` object is the current window containing the form. You should include an javascript event handler in your PRINT-INVOICE.PHP:

```
... <body onload="window.print()"> ...
```