# Run ajax and change page on same time when button clicked

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Hey guys I am still a newbie in ajax. I have a problem with running JavaScript when the button clicked. All I want is, if I clicked the button I can run ajax so ajax can call PHP script and do query, at the same time can change page.

This is my html code

```
<input type="button" onclick="detailbayar()" value="Saya Sudah Bayar" data-theme="b">

function detailbayar()
{
        $.ajax({
                url: host+'/skripsi3/phpmobile/tenantmembayar.php',
                data: { id: user,id1:getacara,id2:getorderID},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result){
                    alert("Payment Accepted");
                    window.location.href="detailpesanan.html";
                },
                error: function(){
                    //output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
                }
            });

}
```

and this is my PHP code

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

$idtenant=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id"]);
$idacara=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id1"]);
$orderID=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["id2"]);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
$tanggal = date("d M Y G:i");
$bayar="telahbayar";
$konfirmasi="On Process";

$query="UPDATE `preorder` SET `tanggalbayar`='$tanggal',`statuspesanan`='$konfirmasi',`statusbayar`='$bayar'   WHERE id_tenant='$idtenant' && id_acara='$idacara' && id_order='$orderID'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Sorry for my bad English, Thank You and have a nice day..
Cheers!!

Comment: If you're changing the page anyway, the point of the AJAX request becomes completely moot.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan is correct. It's better you do a postback

Comment: I am still newbie about ajax, can u give me suggestion or a link so i can learn it? Thank you for your response RoryMcCrossan and vishwakarma09

Comment: Add `type: 'POST'` in your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

If the page changes before your request is completed, your request will be terminated. To achieve your purpose, you can use a form. Set `action` property of the form to `/skripsi3/phpmobile/tenantmembayar.php`. Change the button into a submit button for the form. At the end of `tenantmembayar.php`, add a line to redirect the browser to the page you want to go to.

Read [PHP Redirect to another page after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157685/php-redirect-to-another-page-after-form-submit)

Comment: hey @v7d8dpo4 thank you for your answer, i am sorry i don't get it. Can u give me an example please? or an reference? Thank you