# Report generator - save and redirect to report

Tags: php, redirect, php-7.3

I am creating a report generator, that should save a report and also redirect the user to a version of the report on a specific url (in this case I just added yahoo as test).

Question: Is it possible to save a file and redirect a user to an url in same script?

Problem: The script does the redirect but does not store the file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Report generator</title>
</head>
<body>

<pre>

  <form method="post" action="https://se.yahoo.com" target="_blank">

    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="button_1" value="button_1">

  </form>

  <?php

  var_dump($_POST);

    // Button event listener.

    if (isset($_POST["button_1"])) {

      $json_data = "string";
      $data = json_encode($json_data);

      file_put_contents(
        "user_data/data.txt",
        $json_data
      );

    }

  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This script will never see the POSTED data, you are sending that to `https://se.yahoo.com` So unless you are a YAHOO developer this is not what you should do

Comment: Why the "redirect" tag? I don't see redirection done.

Comment: @RIggsFolly The yahoo site was just a dummy site. I am producing a report so the save is for report saving and the page redirect is for the user to see the report.

Comment: `action=""` then put php at top.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I updated the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Redirect to another page after form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157685/php-redirect-to-another-page-after-form-submit)

Comment: Sure you can save a file then redirect. Just make sure you're not outputting before header when using a header.

Comment: @Salines Just in case, it was not me that DV'd your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `https://se.yahoo.com` is the `action` attribute that is where the form will post the form data to, so it wont go to this script at all

```
<?php

// Button event listener.
if (isset($_POST["button_1"])) {

    $json_data = "string";
    $data = json_encode([$json_data]);

    file_put_contents("user_data/data.txt",$json_data);
    // really not sure if this is what you wanted to do, bit of a guess really
    header('Location: https://se.yahoo.com?fname='.$_POST['fname']);
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Report generator</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form method="post" action="" target="_blank">

    <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="button_1" value="button_1">

  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, so what did I do badly enough to get a DV??

Comment: Sorry its my fail