# How to redirect to parse url (localhost.com/page.php?user=editor) after submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to redirect this url `localhost.com/page.php?user=editor` after submit a form which is **form.php** page and when submit it will redirect to mentioned url.
This url is not fixed it can be changed based on user such as `user/editor/admin/superadmin`.

**Note: I don't know exactly the name of this url parse url or query parameter. Please write me the name of this kind of url.**

Comment: Possible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157685/php-redirect-to-another-page-after-form-submit

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code, hopefully, it will work**

Pass The $newUri.$parm with your form like-

```
$parm=$_GET['user'];
  $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
  $uri = explode( '/', $uri );
 $newUri = $uri[1];
?>
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $newUri.$parm ?>">
```

Redirect from form.php

```
<?php
  $url=$_POST['url'];
  echo "<script> 
    window.location.href='.$url.';
  </script>";
?>
```

Comment: Unable to get the exact vaule after page.com?user=**missing**

Comment: You can try this

Comment: How I will get the parameter from another page? I can get this link page.com?user=

Comment: you can just pass the prams value with the form and from the form.php just use the params value which you pass through the form