# Warning: preg_match(): Empty regular expression in

Tags: php, preg-match

```
$emailPattern = '/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/';

$post_email = strtolower( $_POST[ $field ] );

if( filter_var( $post_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL ) )
{ 
    if( preg_match( $email_pattern, $post_email ) )
    { 
        return $post_email;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}else
{
    return false;
}
```

Is returning:

> Warning: preg_match(): Empty regular expression in
>   /*/functions.php
>   on line

**$_POST[ $field ] successfully contains an email address: "something.something@something.uk.com"**

What might be going wrong?

Comment: [Just use `filter_var()` already.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863)

Comment: You need to learn how to [READ and debug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php) error messages. Everything you needed to solve the problem was in the error message. $email_pattern is not set to anything

Comment: @Anigel - Sorry to waste your time brah! Me and my silly brain :)

Comment: NP, it happens to all of us some times. Thats what Second Eye debugging is all about ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_match( $email_pattern, $post_email )
```

should be

```
preg_match( $emailPattern, $post_email )
```

Your pattern name variable is `$emailPattern` and you are using `$email_pattern`. That is why you are getting warning in `preg_match` function.

Comment: Oh god, sorry to waste your time... I was looking far too deep... Big project, deadlines, sweats. thanks