# warning preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 33

Tags: php, validation

I want to validate an email I've added to use in PHP. For this purpose, I use the below function:

```
function checkEmail($email) {
  if(preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])↪*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/",$email)){
    list($username, $domain) = split('@', $email);
    if(!checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX')) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Now, however, it returns the following warning:

```
preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 33
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's "↪" in the middle of the regexp? It shouldn't be there. Trying deleting the character.

Comment: Let me guess: you copy-pasted that literally from some site including the "line break" visualizer they used to highlight their code...?

Comment: Please do not use `split` ever - it's deprecated. You want `explode`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why `preg_match`, when you can do it using `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` in PHP

```
if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
```

[FILTER](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php)