# php regex error preg_match(): Unknown modifier '['

Tags: php, regex

Iam very new to Php Regex, but somehow learned bit and tried as below, but getting error as : `PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '[' in /home/3ZZyLt/prog.php on line 4`

**Here is the whole code with output:**  `https://ideone.com/fTIyUK`

**Same code from above link:**

```
<?php 
$email = "paulw Paul Walker paulw 2014-12-28 07:18:09 paul@comp.com 2014-12-28 07:18:09 2014-12-28 07:18:09"; // Invalid email address 
$regex = "/[a-z] [A_Z] [A-Z] [A-Z] (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) /[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4} (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/"; 
if ( preg_match( $regex, $email ) ) {
     echo $email . " is a valid email. We can accept it.";
} else { 
     echo $email . " is an invalid email. Please try again.";
} 
?>
```

Please tell me what needs to be changed?

**Updated:**

**Input:** string(a-z) string(a-zA-Z) string(a-zA-Z) string(a-z) date(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) emailid date(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) date(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)

**8 Parameters:**

```
userid (string)   
first name(string)  
last name(string)  
userid(string)  
date  
email
date
date
```

Comment: That's horrible regex to begin with, and not going to work as expected anyway. Why not split on spaces first? It's a space-delimited log/whatever line, isn't it?

Comment: The first four groups only capture one single character. This won't work even if the error goes away.

Comment: [if you're trying to validate an email, you could use filter_var()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522092/should-i-use-filter-var-to-validate-email)

Comment: Is this whole regex to validate an email? Why not `.*?\s+(\S+@\S+?)\s.*`

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you need to do it this way as opposed to using filter_var()?

Comment: @chris85 its not just related to email.

Comment: @Luceos Could you please modify my regex code and make it work? Actually i really didnt understood how to write a better way.

Comment: Fixing your regex to work is a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$regex = "/[a-z] [A_Z] [A-Z] [A-Z] (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) /[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+@[-0-9a-zA-Z.+_]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4} (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/";
```

If you see this regex closely you have an unescaped `/` in the middle of regex but you're using `/` as regex delimiter.

Use this regex instead with an alternative regex delimiter:

```
$regex = "~[a-z]+ [A-Z]+ [A-Z]+ [A-Z]+ (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) [-\w.+]+@[-\w.+]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4} (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})~i";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG1dZ6/1)

Comment: hi, i tried your regex, now getting output as 'invalid', here: https://ideone.com/fTIyUK

Comment: I didn't alter your regex, it is same. I just changed the regex delimiter. Will check your ideone code

Comment: Could you please modify my regex code and make it work?

Comment: If you can update your question with some valid and invalid input sample data then it will be much easier for me to understand and suggest a fix.

Comment: I updated input parameters in my post, could you please look into. and many thanks for trying to help me out. :)