# Do do I make it such that I do not accept @gmail, @hotmail, @yahoo emails entered?

Tags: java, php

I have a subscribe using the email button on my website. How do I restrict people subscribing using @gmail, @yahoo emails?

## LIST EMAIL ADDRESS

```
$recipient = "test@test.com";

# SUBJECT (Subscribe/Remove)
$subject = "Subscribe";

# RESULT PAGE
$location = "https://test.com";

## FORM VALUES ##

# SENDER - WE ALSO USE THE RECIPIENT AS SENDER IN THIS SAMPLE
# DON'T INCLUDE UNFILTERED USER INPUT IN THE MAIL HEADER!
$sender = $recipient;
$email = $_POST[‘emailTextBox’];
if (!strpos($email, '@') || !strpos($email, '.')) {
      echo "Email is invalid";
} else {

}


# MAIL BODY
$body .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST['Email']." \n";
# add more fields here if required

## SEND MESSGAE ##

mail( $recipient, $subject, $body, "From: $sender" ) or die ("Mail could not be sent.");

## SHOW RESULT PAGE ##

header( "Location: $location" );
?>
```

Comment: This [library](https://github.com/stymiee/email-validator) can do this for you

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
$email = $_POST[‘emailTextBox’];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || preg_match('/\@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)/', $email)) {
      // Email is invalid
} else {
    // Email is valid
}
```

- `filter_var`, used with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` filter, will just checks if the email is actually a valid email
- `preg_match` will check now if the email contains the domains you don't want.

---

If you rather want people to susbcribe ONLY with the specified email, you need to do:

```
// ...
$email = $_POST[‘emailTextBox’];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) || !preg_match('/\@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)/', $email)) {
      // Email is invalid
} else {
    // Email is valid
}
```

Notice the `!preg_match()`

---

Using`filter_var`, you may want to consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19522092/14066311) and its answers too.

Comment: Didn't work this way. Not sure what I did wrong here.                                                $sender = $recipient;
$email = $_POST[‘emailTextBox’];


if (!filter_var($email) || preg_match('/\@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)/', $email)) {
      echo "Email is invalid";
} else {

}
if (!strpos($email, '@') || !strpos($email, '.')) {
      echo "Email is invalid";
} else {

}

Comment: Yes, sorry, I missed the filter (`FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`) in the `filter_var` function. I've edited the answer, kindly check it.

Comment: This didn't help either. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: You want people to susbcribe ONLY with gmail, yahoo or hotmail ? Is it that?

Comment: Exact opposite of that. I want to exclude emails including gmail.com, yahoo.com

Comment: So the first answer should work. What response or error are you getting when you use it?