# PHP read from txt file and validate email

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to create a script that validates syntax and MX Record to know if the email is correct.

But for some reason this isn't correct.

Any ideas?

---

My TXT file:

email@facebook.com

email@gmail.com

asdhiadf@fdfsdf.com

---

My PHP Code:

```
$fh = fopen('emails.txt','r');
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {

// Create the syntactical validation regular expression
$regexp = "^([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$";

// Presume that the email is invalid
$valid = 0;

// Validate the syntax
if (eregi($regexp, $line))
{
    list($username,$domaintld) = split("@",$line);
    // Validate the domain
    if (getmxrr($domaintld,$mxrecords)) {
        echo(1) . "--> " . $line . "<br />";
    }
    else {
        echo (-1) . "--> " . $line . "<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo(0) . "--> " . $line . "<br />";
}

}
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Why are you trying to build this yourself? You can do this with existing frameworks/formulas. For example http://www.php.net//manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: whats the problem now? any error?

Comment: Sidenote: [`eregi()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.eregi.php) This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: and you can use simply `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Comment: `split()` has also been deprecated...

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863

Comment: Also "But for some reason this isn't correct." is not a sufficient problem description

Comment: If i use: if (filter_var($line, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) validation, this only return that this is a valid email: asdhiadf@fdfsdf.com . And the other arent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from all of the comments below your question that you should take into account, the reason your code fails, is because of [`fgets()`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.fgets.php).

When you read a line with `fgets()` a new-line character will exist at the end of every line except for the last one, so both your regex and `filter_var()` will always fail except for the last e-mail address (if you don't have an empty line after that...).

To solve the current problem, you need:

```
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  $line = trim($line);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're getting this problem is the `\n` character at the end of each line.

Try removing it like this:

```
while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
  $line = substr($line, 0,-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match` to evaluate regex, and use `explode` to split

```
if(preg_match("/^([_a-z0-9-])([\._a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-])([\.a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/"),trim($email)){
     explode("@",$email);
}
```