# How do I restrict special characters except underscore, hyphen and dot in email field in PHP?

Tags: php, email-validation

This is my code.

```
function emailField($email)
{
return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);   
}
```

and

```
if(emailField($_POST['email'])=='')
  {
    echo "Invalid email";
  }
  else
  {
  echo "Valid";
  }
```

This allows all the special characters. I want to allow underscore, hyphen and dot only. How to avoid?

Comment: Why would you avoid valid emails? `filter_var` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` only validates *valid* emails. Restricting it further means disallowing *valid* emails.

Comment: This characters are perfectly valid in email addresses.

Comment: This will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a RegEx like this:

```
/^[\w\.]+@/
```

Then you should also check if the domain really exists.

PHP:

```
$regex = "/^[\w\.]+@/";
$email = emailField($_POST['email']);

$domain = preg_replace($regex, '', $email); //get the domain of the email address by removing the local-part

//Using checkdnsrr we are checking if this domain is registred
if($email == '' && preg_match($regex, $email) && checkdnsrr($domain)){
  echo "Valid";
}
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Comment: \w includes both underscore and digit characters so you can omit the \d and _ from the expression. Also the characters matched by \w can depend a little on locale.

Answer (score 0):

Use both complicated `filter_var` validation and simple `preg_match` validation.

```
function validate_email_popularly($email) {
    return
        filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
        && preg_match('/\A[\w.-]*+@[\w.-]*+\z/', $email)
    ;
}
```

You should also use  `filter_input` instead of `$_POST`. This function can filter unexpected **Notice: Undefined index** or `Array` into `False`.

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
echo validate_email_popularly($email) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid';
```

Comment: Differ them: https://eval.in/180335