# PHP email validation script

Tags: php, validation, email

My first post here, although i have used this site many times to find fixes for code.

I've been using a script to validate emails on my old host which works fine, the new host however (123-reg) it doesnt validate them correctly at all.

This script actually verifies the existence of an email not just the format of it.

please see the following links
t43.co.uk/emailcheck.php?email=asdasdasd@hotmail.com (works fine)
smile-database.co.uk/emailcheck.php?email=asdasdasd@hotmail.com (always says valid when i know it isnt)

my script is below.

```
function checkEmail( $email, $chFail = false ) 
{
    $msgs = Array(); 
    $msgs[] = 'Received email address: '.$email;

    if( !preg_match( "/^(([^<>()[\]\\\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\"([^\"\\\\\r]|(\\\\[\w\W]))*\"))@((\[([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-z\-0-9áàäçéèêñóòôöüæøå]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}))$/i", $email ) ) 
    {
        $msgs[] = 'Email address was not recognised as a valid email pattern<br><br>';
        return $chFail ? Array( false, $msgs ) : false; 
    }

    $msgs[] = 'Email address was recognised as a valid email pattern';
    //get the mx host name

    if( preg_match( "/@\[[\d.]*\]$/", $email ) )
    {
        $mxHost[0] = preg_replace( "/[\w\W]*@\[([\d.]+)\]$/", "$1", $email );
        $msgs[] = 'Email address contained IP address '.$mxHost[0].' - no need for MX lookup';
    }        
    else 
    {
        //get all mx servers - if no MX records, assume domain is MX (SMTP RFC)

        $domain = preg_replace( "/^[\w\W]*@([^@]*)$/i", "$1", $email );
        if( !getmxrr( $domain, $mxHost, $weightings ) ) 
        { 

            $mxHost[0] = $domain;

            $msgs[] = 'Failed to obtain MX records, defaulting to '.$domain.' as specified by SMTP protocol';
        }
        else 
        { 
            array_multisort( $weightings, $mxHost );
            $cnt = ''; $co = 0; foreach( $mxHost as $ch ) { $cnt .= ( $cnt ? ', ' : '' ) . $ch . ' (' . $weightings[$co] . ')'; $co++; }
            $msgs[] = 'Obtained the following MX records for '.$domain.': '.$cnt; 
        }
    }
    //check each server until you are given permission to connect, then check only that one server

    foreach( $mxHost as $currentHost ) 
    {
        $msgs[] = 'Checking MX server: '.$currentHost;

        if( $connection = @fsockopen( $currentHost, 25 ) ) 
        {
            $msgs[] = 'Created socket ('.$connection.') to '.$currentHost;

            if( preg_match( "/^2\d\d/", $cn = fgets( $connection, 1024 ) ) ) 
            {
                $msgs[] = $currentHost.' sent SMTP connection header - no futher MX servers will be checked: '.$cn;

                while( preg_match( "/^2\d\d-/", $cn ) ) 
                { 
                    $cn = fgets( $connection, 1024 );
                    $msgs[] = $currentHost.' sent extra connection header: '.$cn; 
                }

                if( !$_SERVER ) 
                { 
                    global $HTTP_SERVER_VARS; $_SERVER = $HTTP_SERVER_VARS; 
                }

                //attempt to send an email from the user to themselves (not <> as some misconfigured servers reject it)
                echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "<BR>";
                $localHostIP = gethostbyname(preg_replace("/^.*@|:.*$/",'',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']));
                echo $localHostIP . "<BR>";
                $localHostName = gethostbyaddr($localHostIP);
                fputs( $connection, 'HELO '.($localHostName?$localHostName:('['.$localHostIP.']'))."\r\n" );
                if( $success = preg_match( "/^2\d\d/", $hl = fgets( $connection, 1024 ) ) ) 
                {
                    $msgs[] = $currentHost.' sent HELO response: '.$hl;

                    fputs( $connection, "MAIL FROM: <$email>\r\n" );
                    if( $success = preg_match( "/^2\d\d/", $from = fgets( $connection, 1024 ) ) ) 
                    {
                        $msgs[] = $currentHost.' sent MAIL FROM response: '.$from;

                        fputs( $connection, "RCPT TO: <$email>\r\n" );
                        if( $success = preg_match( "/^2\d\d/", $to = fgets( $connection, 1024 ) ) ) 
                        {
                            $msgs[] = $currentHost.' sent RCPT TO response: '.$to;
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                            $msgs[] = $currentHost.' rejected recipient: '.$to; 
                        }
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        $msgs[] = $currentHost.' rejected MAIL FROM: '.$from; 
                    }
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $msgs[] = $currentHost.' rejected HELO: '.$hl; 
                }

                fputs( $connection, "QUIT\r\n");
                fgets( $connection, 1024 ); fclose( $connection );
                //see if the transaction was permitted (i.e. does that email address exist)
                $msgs[] = $success ? ('Email address was accepted by '.$currentHost) : ('Email address was rejected by '.$currentHost);                
                return $chFail ? Array( $success, $msgs ) : $success;

            } 
            elseif ( preg_match( "/^550/", $cn ) ) 
            {
                $msgs[] = 'Mail domain denies connections from this host - no futher MX servers will be checked: '.$cn;
                return $chFail ? Array( false, $msgs ) : false;
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $msgs[] = $currentHost.' did not send SMTP connection header: '.$cn; 
            }
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $msgs[] = 'Failed to create socket to '.$currentHost;
        }
    } 
    $msgs[] = 'Could not establish SMTP session with any MX servers';
    return $chFail ? Array( false, $msgs ) : false;
}    

echo "<br><br>Email Validation Check<br><br>";


$return_msgs = checkEmail( $_REQUEST['email'], true );

if ( $return_msgs[0] == 0 ) 
{
    echo "<img src='img/Fail.png'> May be invalid<br>".$_REQUEST['email'];
}
elseif ( $return_msgs[0] == 1 ) 
{
    echo "<img src='img/OK.png'> Valid<br>".$_REQUEST['email'];
}
else
{
    echo "<img src='img/Caution.png'> Caution<br>".$_REQUEST['email'];
}
```

Comment: What are the PHP versions of both old and new servers?

Comment: http://smile-database.co.uk/info.php http://t43.co.uk/info.php

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: done that. doesnt seem to show anything

Comment: @RyanPatterson take off the error suppression `@fsockopen` to `fsockopen` - see if any errors are thrown

Comment: done that Danny, still no errors.

Comment: Since both versions of PHP aren't that far apart, I can't see why this would fail. Once PHP's done its job, it's done its job. This may very well be on the client-side, along with a form you may be using.

Comment: i am literally using no forms, i obtain the email from the URL with a $_GET

Comment: any ideas? its literally got me baffled.

Comment: @RyanPatterson I don't really buy into this, in my experience there is no reliable way to determine whether a mailbox exist or not. Some server would not provide you this information. You best bet is to try to send the email and look for errors. I also tested your script, sometimes it does not catch non-existing emails

Comment: the script does work fine with hotmail and gmail, which is mostly the emails i validate.

Comment: The problem: https://emailtester.pieterhordijk.com/test-pattern/NTgy | The fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026842/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-php/12026863#12026863

Comment: Thanks for your input, please read my question a bit more, im looking to actually find out if an email address is TRUE not in valid format

Answer (score 0):

I have read [one great topic](http://habrahabr.ru/post/175375/) about email validation.
Author propose to use this regexp: `/.+@.+\..+/i` and give a great description (in Russian) to a lot of "why exactly this regexp"

> 'somestring' @ 'somestring'.'somestring'

Comment: Thanks but i am looking to check the existence of an email by loggin into the server.. the code works on 1 server i have but not another !