# How to Create a Regular Expression Pattern for Emails and then Test it with Scripts?

Tags: php, regex

Got another question. I have this assignment I need to do and I thought I understood what to do, but turns out I don't. So far I have this:

```
([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9_\+\.]*[a-z0-9])@([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\.]*[a-z0-9]\.(com|net|org)
```

Every time I run the php code I get an error (I have the php tags at the start and end of the code just didn't include them). What I need to know is how to display this correctly so I can actually test what I'm supposed to be testing. For reference, this is what I am actually supposed to do.

Design a regular expression pattern that accepts email address

"jsmith456@test.com",  "mjones@study.net",   and  "jane.doe@example.org"

but does not accept  "john.smith@php.test",      "john.jones@php.invalid",    and  "alan.smithee@test".

Test it with a script.

Comment: What is your php code and what error do you get?

Comment: Does it HAVE to be with regex? Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12026863/8837781 (see bottom of answer for REGEX, be sure to reed the NOTE)

Comment: only com net org??? and all the rest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to recommend a Regex online debugger like [regex101](https://regex101.com); it explain part by part your regex code, and what is the function of each part. Also you're missing the `)` that closes the parentheses of `@(`:

```
                                missing the closing parentheses of this.
                                  |
([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9_\+\.]*[a-z0-9])@([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9\.]*[a-z0-9]\.(com|net|org)
```